# Checking if image has left its container?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, containers, carousel, offset

First off, I think I may have some syntax errors, but I don't know where since most of this code is copy paste from JQuery then modified for my needs...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var stage = $(".gallery");
var stageoffset = stage.offset();
var stageleft = stageoffset.left + 600;
var lastimage = $("img:last");
var imageoffset = lastimage.offset();
var imageleft = imageoffset.left;

if(imageleft > stageleft) {
    alert("Passed to the right.");
}

function gallery () {
    $("#image").animate({"margin-left":"+=100px"}, 1000, "linear");
}
setInterval(gallery, 1000);
});
```

Second, here is a JSFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/dHezM/2/

I know that the animation code is right, because that works fine. Since it is not running, I assume there is a syntax error. However, I'm pretty new to JQuery, and I can't find it.

The point of this code is to move the images, then when they leave the container  to the right, the script will alert a message. Eventually, I will use this trigger to delete the last image, and clone it in front to produce a carousel. But, that's later. Am I implementing this code right?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: *"First off, I think I may have some syntax errors, but I don't know where"* The browser will happily **tell** you where. Just look in the console for the handy error messages. The console is accessible from the browser's menus. F12 opens the dev tools on most browsers, and the console is one of the tabs in the dev tools.

Comment: For one thing, you can't use `-` in a JavaScript variable name. E.g., `stage-offset` is an invalid variable name. I recommend reading some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: you variable names are wrong . you cannot use and hyphen "-" in variable names

Comment: That is excellent information, let me change that. :D

Comment: That was the syntax error, thanks! Any idea what I'm doing wrong otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to check if the image is out of the box at document.ready. You can use the `progress` function on animate to get notified about every step of the animation. Then you include your check in that function ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dHezM/4/)).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var stage = $(".gallery");
    var stageoffset = stage.offset();
    var stageleft = stageoffset.left + 600;
    var lastimage = $("img:last");

    function gallery () {
        $("#image").animate({"margin-left":"+=100px"}, {duration: 1000, easing: "linear", progress: checkBox});
    }
    var interv = setInterval(gallery, 1000);

    function checkBox() {   
        if(!(typeof lastimage.offset() === 'undefined'))
        {
            var imageoffset = lastimage.offset();
            var imageleft = imageoffset.left;
            if(imageleft > stageleft) {
                lastimage = lastimage.prev()
                alert("Passed to the right.");
            }
        } else {
            clearInterval(interv);
        }
    }
});
```